# How to FULLY re-enable back/left swipe gesture in UINavigationController after unwind from popped view?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

After unwind from a popped view, my back/left swipe gesture is gone. I fixed by:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  reenableSwipeBack()
}

func reenableSwipeBack() {
  self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
  self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil;
}
```

My swipe gesture is back but without animation (Shown [here](http://gph.is/2unmqBV) (Giphy)). How can I get the gesture animation back?

Comment: Did you hide your navigationbar in pushed viewcontroller?

Comment: @Mohammadalijf yes I did. You can see it in that Giphy link.

Comment: no i get 404 error on Giphy.

Comment: if you hide your navigationbar on push. make sure you show your navigation bar animated in viewWillAppear.

also if you are pushing to Translucent from Non-Translucent navigation bar (or otherwise), you should use custom navigation bar and add it programatically to your view. 

can't really see your Giphy to tell you which case it is. also it would be nice if you tell me where and how you are hiding or showing your navigationbar .

Comment: @Mohammadalijf Thanks for helping. I uploaded to [Imgur](http://imgur.com/oHXMf6r)