# Back gesture animation disappears sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I  got some very strange behaviour for me with back gestures.

When app started - everything is fine, but after some time back animation not working. Just when touch left side of the screen and swipe a little - back action is happening.

I'm hiding and showing navigation bar with different view controllers.

Found same question, but no answer.

gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hidp.jpg

question: 
[How to FULLY re-enable back/left swipe gesture in UINavigationController after unwind from popped view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268086/how-to-fully-re-enable-back-left-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-after-u)

EDIT:
I've found when it happens:

Everything is fine: Launching app, from first tab (no navigation bar, tabbar) clicking tableview cell to push for another VC (navigation bar with back arrow, no tabbar).

Problems comes here: Launching app, click second tab then again first, repeat "fine" version, but back transitions now don't have animations.

Comment: is this issue happening every time only in some screens? Or the issue is happening randomly, even in screens where earlier back action was working correctly?

Comment: I've found when it happens:
Everything is fine: Launching app, from first tab (no navigation bar, tabbar) clicking tableview cell to push for another VC (navigation bar with back arrow, no tabbar).
Problems comes here: Launching app, click second tab then again first, repeat "fine" version, but back transitions now don't have animations.